# How can I move custom panels content from a panel to a mini panel (using Features)?

Tags: panels

I have created a large number of `new custom content` pieces with a rather complicated configuration for `visibility settings`, etc.

However, I now need to re-use this custom content across a large number of panels (originally, I had thought I would only need it for one panel).  So, I want to move the custom content to a mini-panel.

Is there a way to move this content from the panel to the mini panel instead of re-creating it manually?  I am managing deployment through the Features module, so all of my panels and mini panels are already in code.  However, I opened up `myfeature.pages_default.inc` and there is a huge amount of code; I wasn't able to find the positioning information for the panels/mini-panels.

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of would be to move your code into a "real" custom pane. This will make it reusable like any other pane, and stop using eval() to execute it, which is a nice bonus. That pane could then be added into a mini-panel if you still want to. Would that work for you?

Comment: In this case, the custom content is specific to this one particular use case and so I would rather not go the content panes route (being able to edit everything on one screen in panels makes managing the slightly unwieldy mess of custom content much easier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing it manually.  Though it took some time, I was unable to find a faster solution.